# Multiindex Pivot column difference

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I will like to create a column on the multiindex pivot which takes the difference of last two columns (i.e. 2017 - 2016). *I will also like to refer year columns by column number as these years will change in future*

```
raw_data = {'year': [2016,2016,2017,2017],
              'month':[1,2,3,4],
            'area': ['A','B','A','B'],
'age': [10,12,50,52]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['year','area','month','age'])
table=pd.pivot_table(df1,index='area','month'],columns='year',values='age',aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)
```

the new table should look as follows

```
       year     2016    2017    diff
area   month
A      1        10.0    0.0     -10.0
       3        0.0     50.0     50.0
B      2        12.0    0.0      -12.0
       4        0.0     52.0      52.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract columns selected by positions by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
table['diff'] = table.iloc[:, -1] - table.iloc[:, -2]

print (table)
year        2016  2017  diff
area month                  
A    1      10.0   0.0 -10.0
     3       0.0  50.0  50.0
B    2      12.0   0.0 -12.0
     4       0.0  52.0  52.0
```